# How to republish messages with pika and RabbitMQ

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I need to listen to RabbitMQ messages, process each message just a little bit, and submit it to another exchange. Each example I have seen so far includes either this:

```
reader_connection.ioloop.start()
```

or this:

```
writer_connection.ioloop.start()
```

Because I need to both receive and send messages, I probably need to run both loops at the same time. Is there a way I could accomplish that?

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between publishers and subscribers. You can publish and subscribe using same connection or different(then you will need to start ioloop for both of them)
You can find some examples here: https://pika.readthedocs.org/en/0.10.0/examples/connecting_async.html

Comment: All these examples either only publish or only consume. I've read them before posting the question. Thanks a lot!